# How to get the average value of column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have a table like this.

[image: Data Table]

And I want to use SSRS to present the report like this.

[image: Report]

I use a Matrix in this report.  Add [Category], [Commodity] to row group, add [SaleDate] to column group, add Sum(SaleAmount) to column data, add Sum(SaleAmount) for [Commodity] row group, add Avg(SaleAmount) in the last cell.

[image]

But the value of Avg(SaleAmount) is not like (3+5+2)/3 = 3.3333, its value is （2+1+3+2+1+1）/6 = 1.666666....

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What version of SSRS is this? Is it 2008R2 or higher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The average is just the sum divided by the count. In this case the sum is the same, but you want the count to just be the different commodities. Using [CountDistinct](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155923%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) should work:

```
=SUM(Fields!SaleAmount.Value) / COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!Commodity.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution will not work in one situation that when the row total value is nothing of a commodity, for example if Road Bikes row total value is nothing, then the average value should be (3 + 2) / 2 not (3 + 2) / 3, I need to exclude empty value in total column.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=IIF(COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!Commodity.Value) > 0 ,SUM(Fields!SaleAmount.Value) / COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!Commodity.Value),Nothing )
```